# Closed Form Cantor Snake Function

Tags: functions, cardinals, closed-form

Does anyone have the closed form for the Cantor-Snake function and its inverse?

---

By Cantor-Snake, I mean the bijection that maps the Naturals to the Rations - the classic proof that the rationals are denumerable.

I recall seeing the function as follows:

Consider the Natural Numbers, N = { 1,2,3,4... }

Consider the table of (N x N):

| 0  |  1  |  2  | ...  |

| 1  |  2  |  3  | ...  |

| 2  |  3  |  4  |  ... |

And so on. We see that we could map 1 to (0,0), 2 to (0,1), 3 to (1,0), and so, "snaking" through the table. It's clearly surjective, and that's enough to have a bijection in this case (onto from Naturals to an infinite set proves the existence of a bijection).

I want the closed form for that snake function and its inverse. When working with that Rationals proof, we have to skip fractions that reduce - I don't want to skip those, I want to hit all of N cross N.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Cantor pairing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) does what you need.  $(x,y) \to z=\frac 12(x+y)(x+y+1)+y$ is a bijection.  To invert it, let $w$ be the largest natural such that $\frac 12w(w+1) \le z,$ Let $t=\frac 12w(w+1), y=z-t, x=w-y$

Comment: Pairing, not snake, gotcha. Thanks!

Comment: @Ross Millikan, is there a closed-form function the other way around? Namely to go from $z \in \mathbb{N}$ to (x,y) for $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @ENV:  yes, and it is given in a large paragraph in the Wikipedia article I link to.  It is also the second sentence of the answer