# bijection between naturals

Tags: natural-numbers

in https://www.coursehero.com/file/69596247/hw0pdf/ problem 3 asks to find a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}=\mathbb{N}^2$.

Recalling Cantor diagonal proof it is easy to show that such bijection exists. I was wondering if there are other types of a simply linear maps that could give an explicit bijection.

Paolo

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "linear"?

Comment: What is a linear map in this context?

Comment: As I understand it, you want a bijection other than the [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) ([sometimes](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/456922) called a snake). I wouldn't call this proof "diagonal"; that term is [usually used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) for proofs by contradiction certain sets are _not_ related by a bijection.

Comment: linear I mean somethins like $\mathbb{N}  \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \rightarrow (an+b, cn+d)$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function

Comment: That sort of map can't possibly be onto. All points $(x,y)$ in its image would satisfy $cx-ay=bc-ad$, so they would all fall on a single straight line.

Comment: Understood, user?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is not responding.

Comment: thanks everyone for the help and the precious links.